# How to get tags that don't have specific ancestor and descendant using REXML

Tags: ruby, xpath, rexml

I'd like to get A tags and the B tag from the following XML, but I want to remove the second A tag:

```
......many other tags.
<A>abc</A>
<A>   <<==== I want to remove this A tag from result.
  <B>def
    <A>foo</A>
    <A>hoge</A>
    <A>bar</A>
  </B>
 </A>
 .......
```

I'm using this XPath:

```
//*[self::A[not(descendant::B) or self::B]]
```

However this XPath gets the inside A tags of B tag twice:

```
 <A>abc</A>
   <B>def
      <A>foo</A>
      <A>hoge</A>
      <A>bar</A>
   </B>
   <A>foo</A>
   <A>hoge</A>
   <A>bar</A>
```

then, I wrote this Xpath, but it doesn't work:

```
//*[self::A[not(descendant::B or ancestor::B) or self::B]]
```

I want to get this result:

```
 <A>abc</A>
   <B>def
      <A>foo</A>
      <A>hoge</A>
      <A>bar</A>
   </B>

 .......
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I'd recommend using [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org) over REXML. While REXML comes with Ruby, Nokogiri is faster and is the defacto standard. It also supports using CSS selectors in addition to XPath, letting you choose whichever works better for a particular lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below `XPath` expression:

```
//*[self::A[not(./B) and not(./parent::B)] or self::B]
```

Output:

```
'<A>abc</A>'
'<B>def
    <A>foo</A>
    <A>hoge</A>
    <A>bar</A>
  </B>'
```

`self::A[not(./B) and not(./parent::B)]` means `A` that has no direct child or parent `B` element